# Testing emails with symfony

Tags: symfony1

I am testing emails with sfTestMailer (delivery stratagy is none) How can I extract some text from sent email body?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you would have to extend the sfTesterMailer to get the message (which is there, but is protected). Right in your functional test maybe you can do this:

```
class myTesterMailer extends sfTesterMailer {
  public function getMessage() {
    return $this->message;
  }
}

class myTestFunc extends sfTestFunctional {
  public function getMessage() {
    $message = $this->with('mailer')->getMessage();
    return $message;
  }
}

$browser = new myTestFunc(new sfBrowser(), null, array('mailer' => 'myTesterMailer'));

$message = $browser->getMessage();
... do tests on $message->getBody() ...
```

Comment: Why do i need $this->end() in getMessage function?

Comment: You're right, I don't think you need it. (I thought I had opened up a block with begin() but actually I didn't, and shouldn't need to since it's just one call to the mailer tester.) I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you have properly configured your factories, this should work:

```
$browser->
//the rest of your test here
  with('mailer')->begin()->
    checkHeader('Subject', '/Hello world/')->
    checkBody('/Hello stack overflow/')->
  end();
```

More info is available [in the documentation](http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/16#chapter_16_testing_emails).

Comment: What i really wanted is something like $body = $browser->getMailer()->getMessage()->getBody(). The idea is to extract a link that is sent to user in a registration  email and then use it for testing.